# Find the highest point of intersection

Tags: optimization, spheres

> Find the highest point of intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=30$ and the cone $x^2+2y^2-z^2=0$.

Am I supposed to use the Lagrange multiplier for this?

EDIT:
So this is what I've tried...

$z^2=-x^2-y^2+30$ and $z^2=x^2+2y^2$. Then $-x^2-y^2+30 = x^2+2y^2$. 
This gives us $3y^2=-2x^2+30$, which is then: $y^2=-\frac23x^2+10$. Substitute $y^2$ in to the sphere equation, we have:

$z^2 = -x^2 - (-\frac23x^2+10)+30 = -\frac13x^2+20$, so the maximum $z$ is $\sqrt{20}$...?

If this is true, then calculating the rest of the point, we have $(0,\sqrt{10},\sqrt{20})$....?

Comment: Could be wrong but I'd start by solving both for $z^2$ and then by substitution get a curve in $x$ and $y$. Then find max for that curve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Lagrange multipliers, we need to solve system $$F'_x=0,$$ $$F'_y=0,$$ $$F'_z=0,$$ where is $F(x,y,z,\alpha,\beta)=z+\alpha(x^2+y^2+z^2-30)+\beta(x^2+2y^2-z^2)$,

with conditions $$x^2+y^2+z^2-30=0,$$ $$x^2+2y^2-z^2=0.$$

Stationary points are ($\pm \sqrt{15}$,$0$,$\pm \sqrt{15}$) and ($0$,$\pm\sqrt{10}$, $\pm\sqrt{20}$).

We get that maximal z is $z=\sqrt{20}$ (in point ($0$,$\pm\sqrt{10}$, $\sqrt{20}$)).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by John Molokach: solving for $z^2$ yields
$$
2x^2+3y^2=30,
$$
so the intersection of both curves projected in the $x,y$ plane is the ellipse 
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\sqrt{15}\cos t\\
y=\sqrt{10}\sin t
\end{cases}
$$
Replacing these equations in the cone yields
$$
z=\sqrt{15+5\sin^2t}
$$
which has maximum $z_{MAX}=2\sqrt{5}$ with elementary derivative analysis.

Comment: Then find the $t$ that gives $z_{MAX}$ to get $y_{MAX}$ and $x_{MAX}$?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. It is easy to see that $t_{MAX}=\pm \pi/2$ which yields $(x_{MAX},y_{MAX},z_{MAX})=(0,\pm\sqrt{10},\sqrt{20})$.